# Firefox: fast dictionary language switching

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-addons, switch, dictionary

I have two language dictionaries installed on Firefox 3.6, and I would like to be able to switch *really fast* between them, using the keyboard.

At the moment the only way I know I can switch is right clicking in a text input field, go into Language, and then click the language.

I would instead to be able to switch between those two just hitting two keys at most, if possible just one (something like F13).

Searching for addons I've found tons of extensions somewhat related but that don't actually do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the add-on linked in the other answer didn't work for me, I've developed a new one: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/automatic-dictionary-switcher/

Comment: Thank you for your update! I switched to your addon long ago, but I forgot to update this post!

Comment: this addon is no longer available :(

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of anything that employs keyboard short cuts, but if you haven't already found it, try Dictionary Switcher, it's what I use and it works very well.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3414

Comment: Beat me! It usually works well enough in auto but also manually.

Comment: I noticed that but I want it to be keyboard controlled :/ though if the auto-switch really works it would be great: I'll try it

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: well, ok, it's not working *that* bad.

Comment: Haven't used this add-on in Firefox, but I love the auto-switching in Safari (at least when running on a Mac; not sure if Safari on Windows does it as well).

Comment: Ok, it does not really work properly, but at least is somewhat works, and it's better than not having it. Unless someone comes up with a better solution, this is it.

Comment: Doesn't really work anymore.